# Is it safe to name python files with whitespace in them? Or am I just asking for trouble down the line?

Tags: python

Can name python files Hello world.py or Hello_world.py , it't not much effort to choose the later but worth knowing if a problem to choose the first.

Tried both and no problems so far but I've only just started learning.

Hello world.py
OR
Hello_world.py

Edit: This link seemed to provide an answer agreeing with a few points mentioned below;
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308972/python-file-naming-convention

Comment: If you want it to be a *python module* -- something that you can `import` -- stick to names that are legal Python variable names. If it's just an executable and never going to be imported, any software that breaks if your names have spaces is buggy full-stop (but then, you shouldn't be using `.py` extensions, or any other extension, on executable names on UNIX; see the essay at http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ for explanation).

Comment: That's trouble. Keep module names to lowercase `hello.py` or `hello_world.py` as specified in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). Standalone executable files may be named `hello-world`.

Comment: @Hatshepsut, ...standalone executable files could also be named `Hello World` -- sure, there are lots of buggy shell scripts that will break when trying to interact with them, but those scripts are *buggy* (and often have command injection if not just argument injection vulnerabilities), and it's good to actually expose those bugs so they get fixed. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There are lots of buggy programs out there, and naming scripts with whitespace names is asking for trouble for no reason.

Comment: @Hatshepsut, ...I don't consider flushing out bugs no reason, or even a *bad* reason, particularly when those bugs have potential to be security-relevant. Better to make things fail so you know to either fix them or stop using them, than to let them silently look like they're fine (until someone/something malicious generates an intentional trigger).

Comment: (or an unintentional trigger; one extremely expensive data-loss event I was witness to was caused by a buffer overflow in a C library used by a Python module dumping garbage into a filename; that garbage just happened to contain a `*` with whitespace on either side; a buggy shell script tried to delete that file on a storage system in production, and things went sideways from there).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think your comment makes the most sense here, can you add that as an answer for me to mark?

Comment: Frankly, I consider that comment (and the question as a whole) a matter of opinion, and thus off-topic here. So no, I won't be adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'd have to put an extra effort to put the name of the script in quotes when invoking via command line, otherwise, the part of the name separated by whitespace can be interpreted as extra parameters. I think it's a useful habit to avoid whitespaces and stick to a convention of using underscores instead.

Comment: That convention is documented in the Python Style Guide, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).